# MailChimp API 2.0 python new subscriber to groupings

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

How does one add new subscribers to a grouping using the MailChimp API 2.0 in python? Let's say the group_id for two groups are 123 and 456. I'm able to set the email, first and last name for a subscriber, however, the groupings are ignored. What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

```
mailchimp_api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(mailchimp_api_key)
mailchimp_api.lists.subscribe(list_id, {
        'email': email
    }, {
        'FNAME': first_name,
        'LNAME': last_name,
        'GROUPINGS': [
            {'id': 123},
            {'id': 456}
        ]
    }
)
```

**EDIT -
The correct way is:**

```
mailchimp_api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(mailchimp_api_key)
mailchimp_api.lists.subscribe(list_id, {
        'email': email
    }, {
        'FNAME': first_name,
        'LNAME': last_name,
        'GROUPINGS': [{
            'id': grouping_id,
            'groups': ('group name 1', 'group name 2',)
        }]
    }
)
```

Comment: Do you mean to say the email is not added to the groups on mailchimp ?

Comment: Yes, the email isn't added to the groups.

Comment: So, the way it works - A confirmation email is sent to the intended recipient. Once the user confirms, then the email is added to the groups.

Comment: How long after the users confirms will they be added to the groups? In testing, after the user confirms another email is sent to them and doesn't list them as added to any group. Also, in MailChimp I'm not seeing the user added to the groups, which makes me think the code is incorrect.

Comment: i have personally not used the mailchimp api. I use mailsnake, and it works like a charm.

Comment: mailsnake uses the mailchip 1.3 api, which is deprecated. I rather not use a deprecated api.

Comment: hey could you tell me if there is a way to retrieve groups in a list using the api?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code may help you:

```
m = mailchimp.Mailchimp(mailchimp_id)
groupings = [{'name': 'your-group-name', 'groups': ['opt1', 'opt2']}]
merge_vars = {
    'fname': 'first_name',
    'lname': 'last_name',
    'groupings': groupings,
    'GROUPINGS': groupings,
}
m.lists.subscribe(list_id, email, merge_vars=merge_vars, double_optin=False, update_existing=True, replace_interests=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was helpful.